# In parallel programing, does it make sense to only divide a problem equal to the available processors?

Tags: parallel-processing

For example: If I have an array I needed to merge sort, and I only have 6 processors, I would try to divide the array into 6 equal parts. In turn, I would be utilizing all of the processors and not wasting additional time dividing past the available processors because what's the point.

Comment: In theory it's not a bad rule of thumb. In practice, some folk like to leave a core or two for their desktop, some applications do I/O so programmers split into more, smaller parts so there are always small chunks that are runnable while waiting for I/O. In general, IMHO you need to weigh up your priorities, benchmark your code and remain open/flexible to more or fewer processes/threads. Other folks' mileage may vary.

Comment: Another benefit of using an over-decomposition is load balancing. Indeed, sorting parts of equal size should generally result in a similar time for the merge sort but this is not true for all (sorting) algorithms (eg. quick-sort). The cost of the comparison may not be always the same regarding the object you want to sort (eg. strings).